# Remove all elements after given tag

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

The `tag` structure is as follows:

```
<div class="some-class">
  <h3>Foo</h3>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <h3>Bar</h3>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  ...
```

Now I want to remove all elements within the `some-class` tag after I find the `h3` tag. Is there a `nextAll()` method in `JSoup` like there is for `JavaScript`?

Right now I have

```
for (Element el : doc.select("div") {
  if (el.className().equalsIgnoreCase("some-class") {
    for (Element e : el.select("h3") {
      if (e.hasText().equalsIgnoreCase("Bar") {
        removeAllNextPTags();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a nextAll() method in JSoup

You can use `nextElementSibling()` on an element-base or `nextElementSibling()` on a Node-base.

I'm not complete sure if i understand you correct, but do you want to remove *all* elements after a h3 or just p-elements (until another h3 occurs!?)?

Here's how to remove all p-elements, starting from a h3 element with a given text - until another h3 is found:

```
public void removeChilds(Element root, String h3Text)
{
    final Element h3Start = root.select("h3:contains(" + h3Text + ")").first();
    final int h3Idx = h3Start.siblingIndex();

    for( Element e : h3Start.siblingElements() )
    {
        // Skip all nodes before the relevant h3 element
        if( e.siblingIndex() > h3Idx )
        {
            switch(e.tagName())
            {
                case "p":
                    e.remove();
                    break;
                case "h3":
                    /* Stop if there's a h3 */
                    return;
                default:
                    /* Stop also if there's any non-p element!? */
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To do this for all h3 with given text - eg. multiple `<h3>Foo</h3>`-elements with childs - you can replace the `first()` with a loop over the elements found (that's what `select()` returns).

Comment: Now there is `nextElementSiblings()` convenience method, so you don't need to iterate through preceding siblings.